# send an email in python through google smtp

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, smtp

Alright so, I have been trying to send an email through python 3 using the smtplib module. Here is my code. I left out information such as credentials that could be used to identify me.

```
import smtplib
FROM = 'me@gmail.com'
TO = ["receiver@gmail.com"]
SUBJECT = "Hello!"
TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."
message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s
%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
username = 'me@gmail.com'
password = 'password'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

There is just a little problem though, the first time I tried to run my script it gave the following error.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

So I thought, "Well this is weird, I'll try another setup." The thing is though, now even importing smtplib at all gives an error from another file not referencing it as shown as.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tatatat0\Documents\python\business.py", line 6, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Users\Tatatat0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\smtplib.py",
    import email.utils
  File "C:\Users\Tatatat0\Documents\python\email.py", line 47, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'
```

Any idea what could be going on and/or how I could properly use smtp through python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code is in a Python script file named `email.py`.

When you import `smtplib` in `business.py`, `smtplib` tries to import `email.utils`, but it is accessing *your* version of `email.py`, not the one from the standard library.

The easy way to fix it is to rename your script. You will also want to remove the `email.pyc` file as this will continue to be imported even though the `.py` file has been removed.